# ClassCashException on PullToRefreshListView

Tags: android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I am trying to implement the PullToRefresh using ListView from eu.erikw.PullToRefreshListView project. I am using custom adapter to populate my listview. However on onItemClick event, I get this error java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter cannot be cast to com.example.xxapp.RssAdapter where my RssAdapter class is

```
public class RssAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private final List<RssItem> items;
private final Context context;

public RssAdapter(Context context, List<RssItem> items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int id) {
    return id;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.rss_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.itemTitle.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView itemTitle;
}
}
```

and RssItem class is

```
public class RssItem {

private final String title;
private final String link;

public RssItem(String title, String link) {
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}
}
```

and this is the onclick method giving the error

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Log.e("Clicked item", "Position is " +position);

    //line below gives ClasscastException error
    RssAdapter adapter = (RssAdapter) parent.getAdapter();

    RssItem item = (RssItem) adapter.getItem(position);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getLink());

    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),WebViewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("mystring",uri.toString());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Please I need help with the onclick method so I can get the link to display a webpage.

Comment: Does not compile, RssAdapter != Adapter. Also, post your stacktrace, and do you add Headers to your listview?

Comment: also you can use `(RssItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`

Comment: I have a header added but its from the PullToRefreshListView library. Also when I click, I always get the right position. RssAdapter is the name of my adapter, I have edit the post to reflected that.

Comment: the thing is, when you add a header in a listview, it creates a new adapter that is placed between the list and **your** adapter. which means `getAdapter` returns that adapter instead of yours. Either keep your adapter as an instance member, or use the `getItemAtPosition` I posted earlier

Comment: @njzk2, thanks for the comment but 'RssItem item = (RssItem) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);' returns error.

Comment: parent != adapter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way. Before I set the adapter to the listview, I create another listarray with the same form as the RssItem so I can assign the adapter to this listarray. Later on when I need this adapter, I just call the new listarray which in this case is not affected by the header I added to the listview. Thanks njzk2 for your comment about keeping my adapter as an instance member. The solution looks like this:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Log.e("Clicked item", "Position is " +position);
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
    String titleItem = title.getText().toString();

    Log.e("Title", titleItem);

    //RssAdapter adapter = (RssAdapter) parent.getAdapter();

    //RssItem item = (RssItem) adapter.getItem(position);
    RssItem item = itemx.get(position);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getLink());

    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),WebViewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("mystring",uri.toString());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

where itemx is the instance of my adapter. I don't know how effective it is to do this but it worked

Answer (score 0):

You should use that

```
HeaderViewListAdapter hlva = (HeaderViewListAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
RssAdapter adapter = (RssAdapter)hlva.getWrappedAdapter();
```